# HTML5 Create Geolocation object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geolocation

I have a HTML5 app that uses Geolocation. If the user has denied permissions for using geolocation, I would like to pass a default position object `(latitude:0, longitude:0)` so that my app continues to run.

I know how to check for permissions denied, but how can I create the Position object such that it can be passed into the method below?

```
$scope.setCurrentLocation = function(position) {
    $scope.myposition = position.coords;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you just:

```
$scope.setCurrentLocation = function(position) {
    if (position) {
        $scope.myposition = position.coords;
    } else {
        $scope.myposition = {x:x, y:y}
    }
}
```

or something to this effect?